# how to read the input star and calculate the distance in a method and the call the answer in the main?

Tags: java, methods, call, java.util.scanner, program-entry-point

I wanna be able to read the input star and calculate the distance in a method and the call the answer in the main. How do i do this? Here's what I have so far. what this does is it finds the distances of 5 stars which i need to show.

thanks!!

```
package desktop;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 // *import io because of the file writing

public class distance {

public static void main (String [] args) {

double d = place ();
    }

public static double findDistance (String distance)  {


           double result;

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Where would you like to go?");
                System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Enter 1 for Proxima Centauri");
                System.out.println("Enter 2 for Bernard's Star");
                System.out.println("Enter 3 for Sirius A");
                System.out.println("Enter 4 for Epsilon Eridani");
                System.out.println("Enter 5 for Betelgeuse");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();


                double operator;
                int place = sc.nextInt();

                switch (place) {

                case 1:
                    result = timePC ();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Time to Proxima Centauri is: " + String.format("%.4g",timePC()) + " lightyears");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = timeBS ();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Time to Bernand's Star is: " + String.format("%.4g",timeBS()) + " lightyears");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = timeSA ();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Time to Sirius A is: " + String.format("%.4g",timeSA()) + " lightyears");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    result = timeEE ();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Time to Epsilon Eridani is: " + String.format("%.4g",timeEE()) + " lightyears");
                    break;
                                   case 5:
                                       result = timeB ();
                                       System.out.println();
                                       System.out.println();
                                       System.out.println("Time to Betelgeuse is:" String.format("%.4g",timeB()) + " lightyears" );
                   break;
                   default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid function");
                   }
                    return place;

            }

                        public static double timePC () {

                        double result;
                        double CC = 3.16887*Math.pow(10,7);
                        double distance = 4.010*Math.pow(10, 16);
                        double velocity = 3*Math.pow(10, 8);
                        result = (distance / velocity)/CC;
                        return result;
                        }

                        public static double timeBS () {

                        double result;
                        double CC = 3.16887*Math.pow(10,7);
                        double distance = 5.637*Math.pow(10, 16);
                        double velocity = 3*Math.pow(10, 8);
                        result = (distance / velocity)/CC;
                        return result;
                        }

                        public static double timeSA () {

                        double result;
                        double CC = 3.16887*Math.pow(10,7);
                        double distance = 3.592*Math.pow(10, 18);
                        double velocity = 3*Math.pow(10, 8);
                        result = (distance / velocity)/CC;
                        return result;
                        }

                        public static double timeEE () {

                        double result;
                        double CC = 3.16887*Math.pow(10,7);
                        double distance = 2.930*Math.pow(10, 18);
                        double velocity = 3*Math.pow(10, 8);
                        result = (distance / velocity)/CC;
                                    return result;
                    }

                        public static double timeB () {

                        double result;
                        double CC = 3.16887*Math.pow(10,7);
                        double distance = 6.079*Math.pow(10, 18);
                        double velocity = 3*Math.pow(10, 8);
                        result = (distance / velocity)/CC;
                        return result;
                        }
                   }
```

Comment: Can you be specific about what is not working in your code?

Comment: The only thing that your `main` method does is call `place()`, which is missing from the code you posted. All the rest of the code appears pointless, since it appears to never be called. Please edit your question so it presents a question we might be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your main method should probably look something like this:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    System.out.println(findDistance());
}
```

which would require you change your method header for findDistance to be:

```
public static double findDistance ()  { ...
```

(Since you never use the `string distance` parameter).

Answer (score 0):

I changed your method signature since you were not using the variable being passed in and renamed the Distance class properly. I also made the findDistance method not static and the rest of the methods shouldn't be static methods since you could create an instance of the class [Java Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). You also have a couple of unused primitive types that I left in there.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Distance {

 public double findDistance ()  {


 double result;

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Where would you like to go?");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Enter 1 for Proxima Centauri");
      System.out.println("Enter 2 for Bernard's Star");
      System.out.println("Enter 3 for Sirius A");
      System.out.println("Enter 4 for Epsilon Eridani");
      System.out.println("Enter 5 for Betelgeuse");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println();


      double operator;
      int place = sc.nextInt();

      switch (place) {

      case 1:
          result = timePC ();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Time to Proxima Centauri is: " + String.format("%.4g",timePC()) + " lightyears");
          break;
      case 2:
          result = timeBS ();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Time to Bernand's Star is: " + String.format("%.4g",timeBS()) + " lightyears");
          break;
      case 3:
          result = timeSA ();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Time to Sirius A is: " + String.format("%.4g",timeSA()) + " lightyears");
          break;
      case 4:
          result = timeEE ();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Time to Epsilon Eridani is: " + String.format("%.4g",timeEE()) + " lightyears");
          break;
       case 5:
           result = timeB ();
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Time to Betelgeuse is:" + String.format("%.4g",timeB()) + " lightyears" );
         break;
         default:
              System.out.println("Invalid function");
         }
          return place;

        }

        public static double timePC () {

        double result;
        double CC = 3.16887*Math.pow(10,7);
        double distance = 4.010*Math.pow(10, 16);
        double velocity = 3*Math.pow(10, 8);
        result = (distance / velocity)/CC;
        return result;
        }

        public static double timeBS () {

        double result;
        double CC = 3.16887*Math.pow(10,7);
        double distance = 5.637*Math.pow(10, 16);
        double velocity = 3*Math.pow(10, 8);
        result = (distance / velocity)/CC;
        return result;
        }

        public static double timeSA () {

        double result;
        double CC = 3.16887*Math.pow(10,7);
        double distance = 3.592*Math.pow(10, 18);
        double velocity = 3*Math.pow(10, 8);
        result = (distance / velocity)/CC;
        return result;
        }

        public static double timeEE () {

        double result;
        double CC = 3.16887*Math.pow(10,7);
        double distance = 2.930*Math.pow(10, 18);
        double velocity = 3*Math.pow(10, 8);
        result = (distance / velocity)/CC;
                    return result;
        }

        public static double timeB () {

        double result;
        double CC = 3.16887*Math.pow(10,7);
        double distance = 6.079*Math.pow(10, 18);
        double velocity = 3*Math.pow(10, 8);
        result = (distance / velocity)/CC;
        return result;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){

          Distance d = new Distance();
          d.findDistance(null);

        }
 }
```